# R: Color points in PCA based on groups when using autoplot

Tags: r, ggfortify

I have produced a PCA plot, where I plot a number of cells based on their expression of various genes. In this plot, I want to color some of the points in a separate color. I tried to achieve this by creading "groups", where I sort the cells based on their expression or lack of expression of "gene1".

Here's what my data frame looks (gene1, gene2  and cell_1, cell_2 etc. are colnames and rownames):

```
          gene1      gene2      gene3      gene4      gene5
cell_1   0.0000   0.279204  25.995400  46.171700  94.234100
cell_2   0.0000  23.456000  77.339800 194.241000 301.234000
cell_3   2.0000  13.100000  45.309200   0.776565   0.000000
cell_4   0.0000  10.500000 107.508000   3.032500   0.000000
cell_5   3.0000   0.000000   0.266139   0.762981 123.371000
```

Here's the code I use to try to achieve this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

# Group cells based on expression of a certain gene (to use for color labels in the next step)
groups <- factor(ifelse(df$gene1 > 0, "Positive", "Others"))

#Calculate PCs and plot PCA
autoplot(prcomp(log(df[]+1)), colour="Positive")
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'Positive'
```

Comment: You should use the groups variable, not a specific label from the groups variable.

Comment: @Pieter Thank you. I should've mentioned - I tried with "groups" and "Others" also with the same error. (Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'groups')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
df$groups <- factor(ifelse(df$gene1 > 0, "Positive", "Others"))

head(df)
      gene1     gene2    gene3     gene4      gene5   groups
1 0.5638534  8.968558 94.40170  62.93106 290.442698 Positive
2 0.0000000 15.248374 45.87507 204.21703 291.501669   Others
3 1.9059518 19.488162 75.89302  97.69643 177.833347 Positive
4 1.9449987  6.358773 54.97159  41.54307 164.835188 Positive
5 0.0000000 16.568077 31.62370  23.72278  31.774541   Others
6 1.7199368  3.788276 80.51450 102.82221   6.259461 Positive

autoplot(prcomp(log(df[1:5]+1)), data=df, colour='groups')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It returns errors for me:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "groups", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 253
> autoplot(prcomp(log(df[1:5]+1)), data=df, colour='groups')
Error in df[1:5] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

But, inspired by your solution I came up with this which generates an accurate plot but also a confusing warning:
autoplot(prcomp(log(df[]+1)), colour = ifelse(df$gene1>0, "red", "black"))

Warning message:
In if (value %in% columns) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: what does str(df) give you? updated the post with the randomly generated df I used, it should work without error, if your df has same structure. For me df is a data.frame, the classes of all the gene columns are numerics and the groups column is of class factor.